Why is the ice cube not falling into my cup?
When I play the animation, the ice cube just float on the glass but it was supposed to fall inside.



ive downloaded the blend file and messed with some settings. i almost had it work but right now its going into the cup and then flies out of the cup. by any chance you modeled or know the cup structure well?

Yea that's what happening to me too after I change the shape of collusion of the ice into mesh.

I did modeled the cup but I am new to blender and I was just following a tutorial video on YouTube.

you may have to change the type of cup you are using, but what i suggest before you do that is use the remesh modifier (or a quad remesh addon if you have one) to recalculate the polygons. remember to apply when your happy with the look.

in that case may you share the tutorial that you have followed?

https://youtu.be/I6g_B5cXcHg and https://youtu.be/3EskeIwg2hA

this makes more sense. you may have to remesh or find another model online, theres plenty of whiskey glasses. unless if theres someone whos knows blender more than me this is my only suggestions. im glad i can help though

Ok nevertheless thanks alot for your help!

You already have an accepted answer but I want to give you additional information: in the comments you said, changing the Collision Shape to Mesh did not fully work, you thought the objects are too small. That's not exactly correct, or at least you do not have to make them bigger if you want to work with real-life dimensions.
The thing is, when you switch the Collisions > Shape from one of the primitive shapes or Convex Hull to Mesh, Blender will automatically set a Margin of 0.04 m under Sensitivity. So with a whisky glass where the inner diameter is approx. 0.12 m, 0.04 m margin from each side shrinks the diameter by 0.08 m, leaving a circular "tunnel" of 0.04 m width for the 0.035 m squared ice cube... that can hardly work:

So while increasing everything in size might work because the margin becomes smaller in relation to the overall size, this is not necessary for it to work. You could have simply set the margin to 0.00, this will also result in the ice cube not seemingly hovering over the surface of the glass.
By the way, in this case it is not so important because the glass is passive and not moving around, but the origin of the glass is outside its center. For rigid body simulations it is important that at least the active rigid body objects have centered origins, otherwise the distribution of "weight" can be incorrect and lead to weird looking behaviour. And especially on the primitive collision shapes like Box, Sphere etc. the origin has to be in the center to be calculated correctly.
Some more tips regarding the ice cube falling into the glass: when you set the Margin to 0, the cube falls into the glass but might not come to rest and continue "shivering". To change that, go into the Scene Properties > Rigid Body World > Settings and increase the Substeps Per Frame (you can increase the Solver Iterations as well, but not needed here). Don't go crazy with that, 20 is sufficient in this case and too high values may lead to weird behaviour as well.

Another thing is, by default a rigid body object gets a Mass of 1 kg. When you are working with real-life dimensions it can make it look more realistic if you adjust the mass to real-life values as well, an ice cube of the size in your scene would be around 40 g = 0.04 kg. And it is unrealistic that it will not slightly bounce around in the glass, so you might consider setting the Bounciness on cube and glass to a small value > 0.


Thanks for your explanation!

@Codeblues6 You're welcome. I've added a few tips to simulating your ice cube at the end of the answer.

change the shape of the collision to a mesh

Ok so that kind of works but the ice cube would bounce back out of the glass

ive done that to their file but it didnt work

Ok so I kind of figured out what's wrong, apparently the objects size are too small which causes it to bounce off

@Codeblues6 It wasn't the size in itself, but the margin. See my added answer.
